# React app is failed to compile on my machine only

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I try to run a React app using `npm start` it fails with a load of errors from the types: `no-undef` and `no-restricted-globals` while it actually does compile and runs without any problem on my colleagues' machines!

I changed my `npm` and `node` versions to match those on the other machines but I'm getting the same result.

Any idea where else rather in the versions could the problem be?

Here are all the errors:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/app/App.js
  Line 53:  'propsTypes' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 99:  'onChangeRoute' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/app/AppLoader.jsx
  Line 26:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/Login.jsx
  Line 51:   'propTypes' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 57:   'defaultProps' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 87:   'onChangeField' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 100:  'onSubmit' is not defined       no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/Dashboard.jsx
  Line 38:  'metricsRef' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 56:  'onScrolled' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/Overview.jsx
  Line 136:  'onScrolled' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 138:  'renderTiles' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 164:  'setView' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/EventDetail.jsx
  Line 17:  'propTypes' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 49:  'showDetail' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 53:  'renderList' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/Glancemode.jsx
  Line 20:  'metricsRef' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 35:  'onScrolled' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/app-bar/AppBar.jsx
  Line 131:  'toggle' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 135:  'toggleFilters' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 140:  Unexpected use of 'close'       no-restricted-globals
  Line 144:  'gotoAndClose' is not defined   no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/PaymentBrand.jsx
  Line 15:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/PaymentMethod.jsx
  Line 30:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/PaymentType.jsx
  Line 24:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/PaymentStatus.jsx
  Line 29:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/PaymentAmount.jsx
  Line 63:  'propTypes' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 75:  'showAlternate' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 81:  'hideAlternate' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/PaymentDescription.jsx
  Line 9:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/SexyLoader.jsx
  Line 70:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 81:  'hide' is not defined       no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/app-bar/ViewMode.jsx
  Line 17:  'propTypes' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 28:  'changeView' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/TransactionItem.jsx
  Line 65:   'propTypes' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 86:   'defaultProps' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 99:   'getAlignment' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 111:  'formatItemField' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 134:  'showDetail' is not defined       no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/TransactionDetail.jsx
  Line 130:  'propTypes' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 172:  'resolveTripAddress' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 182:  'resolveTrip' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 229:  'resolveCountry' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 254:  'resolveCustomerCountry' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 267:  'editStatus' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 281:  'getInvoiceMenu' is not defined          no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/metrics/Metric.jsx
  Line 140:  'propTypes' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 157:  'defaultProps' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/page-header/DateRange.jsx
  Line 119:  'onOpen' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 126:  Unexpected use of 'close'        no-restricted-globals
  Line 133:  'formatDate' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 137:  'calendarFormat' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 141:  'addFilter' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 157:  'onChangeStart' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 163:  'onChangeEnd' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 169:  'setRange' is not defined        no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/metrics/BasicMetrics.jsx
  Line 75:   'propTypes' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 102:  'defaultProps' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 128:  'el' is not defined            no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/TransactionList.jsx
  Line 37:   'propTypes' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 48:   'listRef' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 49:   'scroller' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 72:   'sortByField' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 98:   'onResized' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 109:  'onScrolled' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 118:  'calculateTiling' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 177:  'getAlignment' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 189:  'showDetail' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 197:  'hideDetail' is not defined       no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/filters/SavedFiltersList.jsx
  Line 38:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 49:  'remove' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 53:  'activate' is not defined   no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/filters/Search.jsx
  Line 43:  'propTypes' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 55:  'performSearch' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 62:  'onChange' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 68:  'clearText' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/filters/FilterSideMenu.jsx
  Line 97:   'propTypes' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 182:  'onChange' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 214:  'performSearch' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/filters/SavedFilters.jsx
  Line 44:  'propTypes' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 57:  'closeDialog' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 63:  'showDialog' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 69:  'save' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 88:  'onChangeViewName' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/currency-switcher/CurrencySwitcher.jsx
  Line 13:  'propTypes' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 19:  'defaultProps' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/popover/Popover.jsx
  Line 14:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 27:  'onOpen' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 33:  Unexpected use of 'close'   no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/TransactionsHeader.jsx
  Line 53:  'propTypes' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 68:  'getAlignment' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/button/Button.jsx
  Line 7:   'propTypes' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 15:  'defaultProps' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

./src/components/transactions/BulkActions.jsx
  Line 44:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 56:  'onAction' is not defined   no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the errors and the webpack config please?

Comment: Try `npm update react-scripts`

Comment: your machine may need some globals dependencies ..

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the actual log errors xD

Comment: @MatanBobi I added examples of the errors. They are too many to add them all.

Comment: @maxwell Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: Wait do you just need to `npm install && npm start`?

Comment: @maxwell yes, this is only what it needs on other machines.

Comment: try to delete all node_modules and npm i again

Comment: @maxwell did it a couple of times. Didn't work.

Comment: @MatanBobi I did another edit. I put all the errors I get while compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everybody, for your attempts to solve my problem. The problem turned out to be in linting! `create-react-scripts` seems to be having linting on its own. When I installed `eslint` the errors started appearing as warnings only, so instead of `not defined` errors I'm now seeing `not used` warnings. At the least the app works and I can handle removing unused variables.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`is not defined      no-undef` means  is not declared  or imported. for example 
 PropTypes need import like `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`. If you did it, make sure you already run `npm install`.

Or make sure with re install dependency. remove `node_modules` folder,
then run `npm cache clean` after that run `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks! I got stuck a couple of times coming back to the app and your reminder helped me. Bad I cant upvote you coz I don't have enough credit.